# apply multiple XSL stylesheets with identical templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I need to apply several XSL stylesheets to an input document but the stylesheet to be imported have some templates named with identical names.

Here is what I need to do:

```xml
<xsl:import href="convert_from_a_to_b.xsl"/>
<xls:import href="convert_from_b_to_c.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="//root">
  <new_root_element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/> <!-- handle some transformations in this stylesheet -->
  </new_root_element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content_to_convert"/> <!-- the element and its content to be transformed -->
  <content>
    <xsl:variable name="convertedContent">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/> <!-- this should be from convert_a_to_b -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$convertedContent"/> <!-- this should be from convert_b_to_c -->
  </content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

convert_a_to_b.xsl

```xml
<xsl:include href="ab_include.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="baseContent">
  <xsl:param name="in" select="//SubRoot/root/content_to_convert"/>

  <!-- more processing -->
</xsl:template>
     
</xsl:template>
```

ab_include.xsl

```xml
<xsl:template name="template-1234">
  <xsl:param name="in" select="."/>

  <!-- more processing -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subSet">
  <xsl:for-each select="./something">
    <xsl:call-template name="template-1234">
      <xsl:with-param name="in" select="./detail"/>
    <xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

convert_b_to_c.xsl

```xml
<xsl:include href="bc_include.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/" name="baseContent">
  <xsl:param name="in" select="//converted_to_a"/>
   
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count($in) gt 1">
                <batch xmlns="">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$in">
                        <xsl:call-template name="subTemplate">
                            <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="value1"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="value2"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </batch>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                xsl:call-template name="subTemplate">
                            <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$in/value1"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="$in/value2"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="subTemplate">
  <xsl:param name="param1"/>
  <xsl:param name="param2"/>
  <!-- more processing -->
</xsl:template>
```

bc_include.xsl

```xml
<xsl:template name="template-1234">
  <xsl:param name="time" select="."/>

  <!-- more processing -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="otherSubSet">
  <xsl:for-each select="./somethingElse">
    <xsl:call-template name="template-1234">
      <xsl:with-param name="time" select="./detail"/>
    <xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Input_file.xml

```xml
<SomeRoot>
  <SubRoot>
    <root>
      <content_to_be_copied_over/> <!-- this I can handle -->
      <content_to_convert>
       <!-- all kinds of data to be converted -->
      </content_to_convert>
    </root>
    <root>
      <content_to_be_copied_over/> <!-- this I can handle -->
      <content_to_convert>
       <!-- all kinds of data to be converted -->
      </content_to_convert>
    </root>
    <root>
      <content_to_be_copied_over/> <!-- this I can handle -->
      <content_to_convert>
       <!-- all kinds of data to be converted -->
      </content_to_convert>
    </root>
  </SubRoot>
</SomeRoot>
```

Output should be:

```xml
<SomeRoot>
  <SubRoot>
    <new_root_element>
      <content>
        <!-- converted content -->
      </content>
    </new_root_element>
    <new_root_element>
      <content>
        <!-- converted content -->
      </content>
    </new_root_element>
    <new_root_element>
      <content>
        <!-- converted content -->
      </content>
    </new_root_element>
  </SubRoot>
</SomeRoot>
```

However, both stylesheets a lot of includes and have several templates with the same name (e.g. 'template-1234') but different parameters. They have no dependency on each other, but deep down in the included stylesheet stacks they might include the same XSL stylesheet.

The above works if I only import the first stylesheet but after adding the second import I get errors about missing parameters.
E.g. I get an error `parameter in is not declared in the called template`.

I cannot change the stylesheets, because they are produced and maintained by a different group. I can only use them.

Is there a way I can isolate the stylesheets so I can use both in 1 stylesheet and indicate which one I want to use?

NB. I use xslt 3.0 in OxygenXMLEditor with Saxon PE 11.4

Comment: It would help if you posted minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the issue. If you are using XSLT 3 and want to chain stylesheet modules you can't change then one way might be to use `fn:transform` to chain the transformations with XPath/XSLT instead of the `xsl:import` e.g. `fold-left(('convert_from_a_to_b.xsl', 'convert_from_b_to_c.xsl'), /, function($a, $s) { transform(map{'source-node': $a, 'stylesheet-node': doc($s) })?output })`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the example. I've tried to reproduce this, and although the error is resolved I still don't get the output I expect. I'm not sure how to fill the parameters $a and $s. Could you elaborate on your example by defining a function or template that includes this fold-left function which takes the 'content_to_convert' as input? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to do anything with `$a` or `$s`, these a parameters of the function argument to `fold-left`. Anyway, I have posted an answer to elaborate the suggestion but I have not tried to incorporate it into your code in detail as input is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate from my suggestion in the comment, as you are using XSLT 3 and as you seem to want to chain stylesheets without being able to edit them, it appears one way is to use `fn:transform` with `fold-left` e.g. `fold-left(('convert_from_a_to_b.xsl', 'convert_from_b_to_c.xsl'), $some-node, function($a, $s) { transform(map{'source-node': $a, 'stylesheet-node': doc($s) })?output })`, perhaps, in the context of your example

```
<xsl:template match="content_to_convert"/> <!-- the element and its content to be transformed -->
  <content>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="fold-left(('convert_from_a_to_b.xsl', 'convert_from_b_to_c.xsl'), ., function($a, $s) { transform(map{'source-node': $a, 'stylesheet-node': doc($s) })?output })"/>
  </content>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't tell in detail what you are trying to achieve and whether the suggestion helps and works out, to provide a working example see the directory https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/tree/master/xslt/2023/chain-stylesheets-using-fold-left which chains three stylesheets `sheet1.xsl`, `sheet2.xsl`, `sheet3.xsl` by using the suggested `fold-left`/`transform` combination from the new main stylesheet `fold-left-transform-sample1.xml` on the input `sample-input1.xml`; the stylesheet doing nothing but the identity transformation plus adding a comment that they processed the input, so with the input being e.g.

```
<root>This is a test sample.</root>
```

the result of processing the input file with Saxon and the XSLT file `fold-left-transform-sample1.xml` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2023/chain-stylesheets-using-fold-left/fold-left-transform-sample1.xsl is e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>This is a test sample.</root>
<!--Processed by https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2023/chain-stylesheets-using-fold-left/sheet1.xsl with SAXON HE 11.5 at 2023-02-28T17:23:57.3777158+01:00-->
<!--Processed by https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2023/chain-stylesheets-using-fold-left/sheet2.xsl with SAXON HE 11.5 at 2023-02-28T17:23:57.406232+01:00-->
<!--Processed by https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/master/xslt/2023/chain-stylesheets-using-fold-left/sheet3.xsl with SAXON HE 11.5 at 2023-02-28T17:23:57.4349873+01:00-->
```

The stylesheet does e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="xslt-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'sheet1.xsl', 'sheet2.xsl', 'sheet3.xsl'"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="fold-left($xslt-uris, /, function($a, $s) { transform(map{'source-node': $a, 'stylesheet-node': doc($s) })?output })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. While applying it to my own situation I noticed that the a_to_b and b_to_c stylesheets have a different initial template than I initially assumed. I've updated my initial post to reflect that. I'm now running into the situation that none of the stylesheets are called. How can I fix the function($a,$s) to reflect the 'in' parameter with different inputs per stylesheet?

Comment: @hepabolu, I don't see any minimal but complete samples allowing me to understand/reproduce that "none of the stylesheets are called". I am not sure what you want to "fix" about `fold-left` and the arguments of its dynamic function parameter, the `$a` is the "accumulated" value i.e.  first the initial node, then the node after processing the initial node with the first stylesheet, then the node after processing the first result with the second stylesheet, the `$s` is the current item in `$xslt-uris` being processed.

Comment: So the whole idea of using `fold-left` with a sequence of stylesheet URIs is only useful if you want the same `fn:transform` call chaining for each processed stylesheet. If you don't want that then you can perhaps use `fn:transform` without `fold-left` and just make sure you call the one stylesheet as you need it and process the result on to the second stylesheet as you need it. `fn:transform` allows you to set global stylesheet parameters, initial templates etc.